# How does the hardness of the HSP change when the hiding function is altered?

Tags: quantum-circuit, hidden-subgroup-problem, graph-isomorphism

When talking about many (presumably) NP-intermediate problems, such as factoring and graph isomorphism, the HSP is brought up. The HSP, as a problem, is often paired with a group, $G$, and an oracle, $f$, that maps $f \colon G \mapsto X$, where $X$ is a set.

How does the hardness of the HSP change when this function, $f$, and its corresponding set, $X$, are changed?

My most convenient example is the graph isomorphism problem, which is linked to the HSP on the symmetric group, $S_N$, with the function $f \colon S_N \mapsto G$, where $G$ is the set of all graphs on $n$ vertices. To solve the graph isomorphism problem, the function $f$ is given as:

$$
f(\sigma) = \sigma^\dagger G \sigma
$$

where $G$ is the disjoint union of the two graphs we want to find an isomorphism between (its adjacency matrix), and $\sigma$ is a permutation.

What if we changed the function to something else, that still had a hidden subgroup; would it reduce to the same HSP as Graph Isomorphism?